# Ledger Blake2b hash calculation

Tags: tezos-client, ledger, operation, hash

How is the “Ledger Blake2b hash” calculated by the tezos-client and the Ledger? I can calculate the other hashes, but unable to figure out the “Ledger Blake2b hash”:

```
Raw Script-expression-ID-Hash: 0xfe0f19b14a46b7e60df6329444f2e248be9f52e72a0dc2cdc558725cad345689    
Ledger Blake2b hash: J6junU7NtmNS9S71Z2W2Q7PuqCyuAX7YZADqB7hP1Poe                                   
Raw Sha256 hash: 0xd63ad933f6cfc82a6084811e8cc737ffad709fd744e05ec0c1fef8622155a1a2                                                          
Raw Sha512 hash: 0xcd393557d0cb6104869dadf16d77ab24956b1d147fd53388705b3a6805b7eaf2c6df68b9e302e6cb237c40a4fc222d1b9249b57745d1fb73c35fc2b82dbb9535
```

Tried to look it up in the code, but I’m not able to understand what it exactly does:

https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/blob/master/src/proto_007_PsDELPH1/lib_client_commands/client_proto_programs_commands.ml#L374

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr: we serialize the michelson value to binary, we then hash those
bytes it with Blake2b-256. We base58 encode the result.

## Long version

Let's consider the case of the Ledger Blake2b has of the
integer 1, as given by:

```
$ tezos-client hash data 1 of type int
Raw packed data: 0x050001
Script-expression-ID-Hash: expru2dKqDfZG8hu4wNGkiyunvq2hdSKuVYtcKta7BWP6Q18oNxKjS
Raw Script-expression-ID-Hash: 0x438c52065d4605460b12d1b9446876a1c922b416103a20d44e994a9fd2b8ed07
Ledger Blake2b hash: 5YgR7rjfSbSbzGEYhhBG9ENRHhdVSUu2TJ6RyNLawjiv
Raw Sha256 hash: 0x57072915640d052f4e2843e1498b10c4f71b62df565525d33c4a66a724e3e20a
Raw Sha512 hash: 0x112e6b61a60ecf001d501f39284ff8a575d818f2f79295b90b24f045d165a490c19cac2add9149dbdd23a8f2cf956dbee0efe17449111e6326e97ab21532f445
```

How do we go from `1` to `5YgR7rjfSbSbzGEYhhBG9ENRHhdVSUu2TJ6RyNLawjiv`?

In protocol 007, the result of this operation is given by
`src/proto_007_PsDELPH1/lib_client_commands/client_proto_programs_commands.ml`
on line
[374](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/blob/master/src/proto_007_PsDELPH1/lib_client_commands/client_proto_programs_commands.ml#L374):

1. First, on line
   [369](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/blob/master/src/proto_007_PsDELPH1/lib_client_commands/client_proto_programs_commands.ml#L369),
   the data is packed(*), that is serialized, to a binary
   representation. This is handled by the function
   `Script_expr_hash.hash_bytes`.
   This result of this operation is `0x050001`. That is the three
   bytes [5, 0, 1].

   We can replicate this using the [pytezos python library](https://pytezos.org/),
   and more specifically using the [`pytezos.michelson.pack`](https://pytezos.org/pack.html#module-pytezos.michelson.pack) function:

   ```
   >>> import pytezos
   >>> pytezos.michelson.pack.pack({'int': 1}, {'prim': 'int'})
   b'\x05\x00\x01'
   ```

   Aside: `{'int': 1}` and `{'prim': 'int'}` are the micheline
   representation, in JSON, of the michelson value `1` respectively
   the michelson type `int`.
2. Then, on line
   [390](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/blob/master/src/proto_007_PsDELPH1/lib_client_commands/client_proto_programs_commands.ml#L390),
   In the source code, this byte sequence is applied as follows:

   ```
   Base58.raw_encode Blake2B.(hash_bytes [bytes] |> to_string)
   ```

   this is equivalent to

   ```
   Base58.raw_encode (Blake2B.to_string (Blake2B.hash_bytes [bytes]))
   ```

   In other words we:

   1. Hash the byte sequence using the Blake2B module. To be precise,
      this module implements Blake2b-256 with a digest size of 32
      bytes.

      We can try this out using the OCaml REPL utop (this requires
      that you have utop installed and are in the root of the Tezos
      source tree):

      ```
      $ dune utop src/lib_crypto/
      utop # let hash_in_bytes = Blake2B.hash_bytes [Bytes.of_string "\x05\x00\x01"] ;;
      val hash_in_bytes : Blake2B.t = <abstr>
      ```

      We can inspect the hash's bytes in hex:

      ```
      utop # Blake2B.to_hex @@ hash_in_bytes ;;
      - : Hex.t = 438c52065d4605460b12d1b9446876a1c922b416103a20d44e994a9fd2b8ed07
      ```

      We can do the same thing in pytezos:

      ```
      >>> import pytezos
      >>> hash = pytezos.crypto.blake2b(b'\x05\x00\x01', digest_size=32)
      >>> hash.hexdigest()
      '438c52065d4605460b12d1b9446876a1c922b416103a20d44e994a9fd2b8ed07'
      ```
   2. We then convert the byte sequence to a string and base58-encode it.

      Again, In OCaml:

      ```
      utop # Base58.raw_encode ( Blake2B.to_string hash_in_bytes ) ;;
      - : string = "5YgR7rjfSbSbzGEYhhBG9ENRHhdVSUu2TJ6RyNLawjiv"
      ```

      In python, we can use the base58 library to encode the hash.
      We first retrieve the underlying byte sequence of the
      hash using hash.digest, and then pass it to base58:

      ```
      >>> import base58
      >>> base58.b58encode(hash.digest())
      b'5YgR7rjfSbSbzGEYhhBG9ENRHhdVSUu2TJ6RyNLawjiv'
      ```

(*) I will not go into the details of serialization, as it has been
covered extensively in other resources, please ask if you want
more information about this.

Comment: Awesome! Many thanks for your fast and detailed answer!

For console: echo '050001' | xxd -r -p | b2sum -l 256 |xxd -r -p |base58